# How to declare a respository populator bean using java config instead of XML?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I am working on a Spring based project that is (so-far) completely XML-free, except now I've hit a wall with the Spring JPA repository populator:

```
<repository:jackson-populator location="classpath:data.json" />
```

How would the above be expressed in a java @Configuration class?

This post suggests using the FactoryBean directly:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13566712/1746274

I tried that and the closest I got was the following but it's not quite right.

```
@Bean(name="repositoryPopulator")
public RepositoryPopulator getRespositoryPopulator() throws Exception {
    final JacksonRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory =  new JacksonRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
    factory.getObject().setResourceLocation("classpath:test-data.json");
    factory.afterPropertiesSet();
    return factory.getObject();
}
```

The above results in a `FactoryBeanNotInitializedException` with the message `JacksonRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean does not support circular references`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It's straight-forward actually:

```
@Configuration
class ApplicationConfig {

  @Bean
  public JacksonRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean repositoryPopulator() {

    Resource sourceData = new ClassPathResource("test-data.json");

    JacksonRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory = new JacksonRepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
    // Set a custom ObjectMapper if Jackson customization is needed
    factory.setObjectMapper(…);
    factory.setResources(new Resource[] { sourceData });
    return factory;
  }
}
```

By returning the `FactoryBean` itself, Spring will take care of invoking all the necessarry callback interfaces (i.e. `setApplicationContext(…)`, `setBeanClassLoader(…)` etc.). The factory bean is an `ApplicationListener` and thus will listen to the `ContextRefreshedEvent` and trigger population when the `ApplicationContext` is fully initialized.

Comment: With spring-data-commons--1.12.3.RELEASE the class name is `Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean`.