# How do I properly configure my Spring Boot application?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

Using `mongodb` with Spring Data MongoDB backend. Using Mongo Repositories too.

This is my actual configuration:

```
/** MONGO CLIENT *****************************************************/

@Override
protected String getDatabaseName() {
    return db;
}

@Override
public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {

    /* I'm so dump to automatize this that I just do it manually */

    return new Fongo("meh").getMongo();   //Using it for unit tests
    //return new MongoClient(url, port);  //Using it for IT
}

@Override
protected Collection<String> getMappingBasePackages() {
    return Arrays.asList("com.foo");
}


/** BEANS ************************************************************/

@Bean
public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean repositoryPopulator() {

    Resource foo1 = (Resource) new ClassPathResource("collections/foo1.json");
    Resource foo2 = (Resource) new ClassPathResource("collections/foo2.json");


    Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory = new Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
    factory.setResources(new Resource[] { foo1, foo2 });
    return factory;
}
```

[The repository populator is what I added](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13897926/how-to-declare-a-respository-populator-bean-using-java-config-instead-of-xml/13901416) and it's what gives me troubles. 
When I compile and **test** my project I'm getting `DuplicateKeyException` because I guess the repository populator triggers more than once.

These are the annotations that I use on my test classes:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
```

Is it well configured my application? What's the reasonable solution to avoid repository populator to trigger multiple times ?

Comment: Please be clear on what are you trying to do. So that people can suggest you alternative / better solutions.  Are you trying to write tests using in memory mongo(Fongo) with some sample json files which needs to be filled to this before you run your test cases?

Comment: @pvpkiran No, when I run unit tests I don't need my database. It's when I run integrate tests that I need my database (using `MongoClient()` instead of `Fondo()`) to be fulfilled, but I'm getting DuplicateKeyException because the population is executed more than once

Comment: Actually, the collections that I want to fulfill my database are "static", they aren't entities that changes during time. So basically I want to load these collection in the only case that they are empty

Comment: I am not sure if I understood your question directly. However can you show the snippet of foo1.json and foo2.json and Also if you want to use Fongo  for tetsing with prefilled data, Check this out https://ivanursul.com/spring-data-mongo-testing-using-in-memory-db/,    and  https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit

Comment: @pvpkiran they are the usual combo lists: languages, countries... I will take a look at that article, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution based on this guide (in spanish, sorry): https://www.paradigmadigital.com/dev/tests-integrados-spring-boot-fongo

1. Is needed to separate fongo configuration from mongo.
2. fongo configuration must be placed on `test/`

Just take the [example code](https://github.com/paradigmadigital/test-springboot-fongo) (and using MongoConfiguration.java too, my actual config is wrong) from the guide as a base and you will be fine.

Comment: I have taken reference of example code from github link. #Bean
    MongoClient mongoClient() gets called from My MongoConfig-which is trying to connect to real database) - java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext error while executing Integration test. What needs to be done? any idea ?