# Can I use repository populator bean with fongo?

Tags: mongodb, unit-testing, spring-data, fongo

I'm using Fongo not only for unit tests but also for integration tests so I would like to initialize Fongo with some collections, is that possible?

This is my java config ([based on Oliver G. answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13901416/2968729)):

```
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { 
    EmbeddedMongoAutoConfiguration.class,
    MongoAutoConfiguration.class,
    MongoDataAutoConfiguration.class
})
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.foo" },
    excludeFilters = { @ComponentScan.Filter(classes = { SpringBootApplication.class }) 
})
public class ConfigServerWithFongoConfiguration extends AbstractFongoBaseConfiguration {

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ConfigServerWithFongoConfiguration.class);

    @Autowired
    ResourcePatternResolver resourceResolver;

    @Bean
    public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean repositoryPopulator() {

        Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory = new Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
        try {
            factory.setResources(resourceResolver.getResources("classpath:static/collections/*.json"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.error("Could not load data", e);
        }
        return factory;
    }

}
```

When I run my IT tests, on the log it appears `Reading resource: file *.json` but the tests fails because they retrieve nothing (null) from Fongo database.

Tests are annotated with:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes={ConfigServerWithFongoConfiguration.class})
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@TestPropertySource(properties = {"spring.data.mongodb.database=fake"})
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_CLASS)
```

Comment: Have you though of using https://github.com/lordofthejars/nosql-unit. With this it is much more simpler to initialize database with sample data. here is an example as well https://ivanursul.com/spring-data-mongo-testing-using-in-memory-db/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lol, I feel so stupid right now. Was format issue. JSON collections must be formated like this:

```
[
  {/*doc1*/},
  {/*doc2*/},
  {/*doc3*/}
]
```

I was missing the `[]` and comma separated documents.